# How to control a Link on react-router

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a login, I verify the input and the data, the problem is that I don't know how to disable the Link when the Input is wrong. I mean I don't want the login to continue when the username and the password is wrong.

Can I disable the Link? or I need another solution
I really can't think of another solution, hope you can help me.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    info: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    login: {
      email: 'Email.@gmail.com',
      password: '1234'
    }
  };

  updateInfo = e => {
    this.setState({
      info: { ...this.state.login, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });
  };
  submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      this.state.info.email === this.state.login.email &&
      this.state.info.password === this.state.login.password
    ) {
      console.log('true');
    } else {
      console.log('false');
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-center container mt-4" style={{ width: '50%' }}>
        <form className="px-4 py-3" onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email@example.com"
              className="form-control"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.info.email}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="form-control"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.info.password}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <Link to="Profile">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
              Sign in
            </button>
          </Link>
          <div>
            <Link to="/register" className="badge badge-light p-2 m-2">
              Register
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: Honestly, your entire approach is incorrect. Why are you comparing emails and passwords in the frontend? How do you populate the login information in the state (this.state.login)? Typically, what you'd want to do is send username and password securely (post request correct headers etc). Check username and password in server (check should be against a hashed password!!!). Then respond with some sort of success message. If everything is successful then you update your state to allow a user to view the rest of the page. My explanation is not thorough enough, but should get you thinking.

Comment: I have started learning react, honestly I know just frontend, so I dont know how it works in the backend or database, just trying to practice with react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new field in state isValueCorrect:

```
class Index extends Component {
    state = {
        isValueCorrect: false,
        info: {
          email: '',
          password: ''
           },
        login: {
            email: 'Email.@gmail.com',
            password: '1234'
        }
      };
```

then check the values of password and login in  **updateInfo**  and if login and password are correct call **this.setState({isValueCorrect: true})** method and then use simple if statement in your component in curly brackets like this:

```
  { this.state.isValueCorrect === true ?
      ( <Link to="Profile">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
          Sign in
        </button>
      </Link>)
     :
     (null)
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I solved this, instead of the null, I put the button without the link

Answer (score 0):

```js
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
          Sign in
</button>
```

all you need to remove the Link and keep the button
then after the sign in succeeded then you can use:-

this.props.history.push('/Profile');

or
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

```
<Redirect to='/target' />
```